# Input string data from ofstream into vector

Tags: c++

I created a looping statement that consists of reading a string into a vector using its push_back() method.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

ofstream inputReference;

int main() {
    vector <string> productline;
    string placeholder;
    cout << "Product Structure : [Product Name,Original Price,Type of Product] \n";
    cout << "Enter to record product: \n";
    while (placeholder != "stop") {
        cin >> placeholder;
        productline.push_back(placeholder);
        inputReference.open("C:\\Users\\pacar\\source\\repos\\Price Reference Tindahan\\Price Reference Tindahan\\Reference.txt", ios::app);
        for (int x = 0;; x++) {
            inputReference << productline[x] << endl;
        }           
    }
    inputReference.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it states the vector subscript is out of range.

Comment: What debugger do you have access to?

Comment: local windows debugger

Comment: Run this in debug mode and see what the variables are when you get a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Well, if you start an infinite loop, counting `x` from 0, all the way up until infinity, then at some point `productline[x]` is going to be out of range, isn't it? Doesn't that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is an infinite loop that exceeds the bounds of the vector. Use the vector's `size()` method to know how many strings are in the vector:

```cpp
for (size_t x = 0; x < productline.size(); ++x) {
    inputReference << productline[x] << endl;
}
```

That being said, your `for` loop does not make sense inside of the `while` loop. It should be moved after the `while` loop:

```
int main() {
    vector <string> productline;
    string placeholder;

    cout << "Product Structure : [Product Name,Original Price,Type of Product] \n";
    cout << "Enter to record product: \n";

    while ((cin >> placeholder) && (placeholder != "stop")) {
        productline.push_back(placeholder);
    }

    ofstream inputReference("C:\\Users\\pacar\\source\\repos\\Price Reference Tindahan\\Price Reference Tindahan\\Reference.txt", ios::app);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < productline.size(); ++x) {
        inputReference << productline[x] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```